# How can I insert an extra entry in a Biblatex bibliography to refer to another entry?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

This documents yields the output below it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\Textcite{knuth:ct:a} and \textcite{vangennep}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I best add an extra line to refer to another entry (or author) in the bibliography, like a line
"Gennep, see Van Gennep." to facilitate for readers who I suspect will look for that author under G?

(My question is not specifically about how to handle names with prefixes and maybe sort them differently. That was just something that exists in `biblatex-examples.bib` which I could use as example. There could be several reasons for wanting to refer to somewhere else in a sorted bibliography.)

I'll give my own workaround as an answer, but hope for better answers!

Answer (score 1):

You could have a special bibliography driver for "extra" lines like that. This one only uses `author` and `note`.

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{extra}{%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printnames{author}%
  , see\addspace
  \emph{\printfield{note}}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}
\Textcite{knuth:ct:a} and \textcite{vangennep}.
\nocite{extragennep}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

where the extra entry `extragennep` is defined in a bib file as

```
@extra{extragennep,
  author =   {Gennep},
  note =     {Van Gennep}}
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: The driver would be slightly more idiomatic as https://gist.github.com/moewew/c317010d186093f1ce74c3e6e5b5794b. Punctuation should usually be wrapped in a `\setunit` in drivers and bibmacros.